# Add consecutive numbers to a limit, display how many iterations

Tags: c#

I'm learning C# by myself by book and would appreciate some help. I want to create a console program that adds consecutive numbers together until the total reaches a limit defined by the user. The program will then count and display how many iterations were performed.

This is the exercise as stated in the book:

> In birthday cakes, people used to put as many candles as the number of years to celebrate. Assume that candles are sold in boxes of x pieces. Now suppose that a newborn child received his first box of birthday candles. Write a program that tells you after how many birthdays one needs to buy new box of candles

Edit: it works now - new code below.

```
using System;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int x, y = 0, z = 0, a = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("This program will calculate when you have to buy a new box of candles.");
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of candles the box contains: ");
        x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        while (x > 0)
        {
            z = z + 1;
            a = a + z;

            y = x - a;

            if (y <= z)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("After {0} years you have to buy a new box of candles.", z);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see the description of your algorithm. So your question is not clear.

Comment: _adds consecutive numbers together until the total reaches a limit defined_ for that, you can write `result += years` in your loop, _The program will then count and display how many iterations were performed_ for that, you can write `result++` in your loop. Other than that, your question is not clear.

Comment: @Soner Gönül I altered my solution  to include your suggestion. I ran the program and entered 20 and the result was 231. My previous attempts all ended up in the same result.

Comment: @BadtotheClone - Is this code in your comment the answer to your question? I don't know what your asking from us?

Comment: The code in my comment is my 4th attempt. I simply don't know what to put in the loop to get the results I want: the number of iterations it takes for the candles to be used up.

Comment: @BadtotheClone - Can you describe the rule for how the candles get used up?

Comment: Here is the excercise from the book: "In birthday cakes, people used to put as many candles as the number of years to celebrate. Assume that candles are sold in boxes of x pieces.  Now suppose that a newborn child received his first box of birthday candles. Write a program that tells you after how many birthdays one needs to buy new box of candles."

Comment: What's going wrong with it now? By the way, you really shouldn't use variable names like `x`, `y`, and `z`: more descriptive names are much better for readability and to make sure you understand your own program, and there's no downside to using them. It's really hard to tell what `y` is, especially when it doesn't appear to be necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve your problem:

For your example with 20 candles, count_birthdays would be **6** after the loop, because you need 1+2+3+4+5 = 15 candles for the first 5 birthdays, so you won't have left over enough for the **sixth**.

```
int count_birthdays = 0;
int used_candles = 0;
while (used_candles <= candles)
{
    count_birthdays++;
    used_candles = used_candles + count_birthdays;
}
```

Comment: This might help you better understand what I mean. Here is the excercise from the book: "In birthday cakes, people used to put as many candles as the number of years to celebrate. Assume that candles are sold in boxes of x pieces. Now suppose that a newborn child received his first box of birthday candles. Write a program that tells you after how many birthdays one needs to buy new box of candles."

Comment: Is it mandatory to use a for-loop? I think while-loop would be better in this case...

Comment: I edited my code. Now it should solve your problem. if not, just leave another comment :)

Comment: This code is wrong. The answer to the question when `candles == 20` is `5`, not `6`.

Answer (score -1):

A hint would be that there is a '[break](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adbctzc4.aspx)' keyword that will let you exit a loop.

Also, when you get to the 'while' loop, you may find this is a better way to express your solution. For now, look up 'break'